# How to use ModelMultipleChoiceFilter in django_filters with JSONfield

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm try filter items use `django_filters` with **JSONfield** in my model, but I can't do this.

If use `CharFields` I can get current result, but me need have possibility work on requests.
When I use `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter` I get all variations from filter, but filtering does not happen.

`Models.py`

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    properties = JSONField(default=dict, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
```

`Filters.py`

```py
from django_filters.rest_framework import FilterSet
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from products.models import Product

class ProductFilter(FilterSet):
    color = filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Product.objects.extra(
        select={'color': "properties->>'color'"}).values_list('properties__color', 
                                                             flat=True).distinct(), 
        field_name='properties', 
        to_field_name='properties',
        lookup_expr='color__contains', 
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = {
            'color': 'color__contains',
        }
```

`This is Item`

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Test_3",
    "properties": {
        "color": "Black",
        "invertor technology": false,
        "service area, m²": 24
    },
},
```

If I choose in filter color Black,
I have this error: **Choose the correct option. Black is not among the valid values.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out very simple, just had to use `AllValuesMultipleFilter`

```py
class ProductFilter(FilterSet):
    color = filters.AllValuesMultipleFilter(
        field_name='properties__color',
        lookup_expr='contains,
    )
```

Great thanks to [rpkilby](https://github.com/rpkilby).
Link this [issue](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/1100).